# RadioGrup Listener Show Error

Tags: java, android, radio-button, listener

i'm facing a problem on RadioGroup Listener, i'm a little noob with android, and i would appreciate your help.

I have 5 radiobuttons and every button got a different value.

[image]

Here's the following code on java

```
package com.com.calculartmb;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// variaveis

double altura;
double peso;
double resultado;
double nivel;

EditText pesoEd;
EditText alturaEd;
EditText finalEd;

SeekBar altSeekBar;
SeekBar pesoSeekBar;

RadioButton radio1;
RadioButton radio2;
RadioButton radio3;
RadioButton radio4;
RadioButton radio5;
RadioButton radioGrupo;

private double[] checklistValues = new double[6];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // iniciação
    pesoEd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    alturaEd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    finalEd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    altSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    pesoSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);

    radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    radio2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    radio3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    radio4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio4);
    radio5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio5);
    radioGrupo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

    altSeekBar.setMax(25000);
    pesoSeekBar.setMax(60000);


    //listeners
    addChangeListenerToRadios();
    altSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(altSeekBarListener);
    pesoSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(pesoSeekBarListener);

}

private OnSeekBarChangeListener pesoSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Calcula o novo valor do TIP
        peso = (pesoSeekBar.getProgress()) * .01;
        // mostra na caixa o valor novo
        pesoEd.setText(String.format("%.02f", peso).replace(',', '.'));
        // Chama o update
        updateValorTMB();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};

private OnSeekBarChangeListener altSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Calcula o novo valor do TIP
        altura = (altSeekBar.getProgress()) * .01;
        // mostra na caixa o valor novo
        alturaEd.setText(String.format("%.02f", altura).replace(',', '.'));
        // Chama o update
        updateValorTMB();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};

private void updateValorTMB() {

    double peso = Double.parseDouble(pesoEd.getText().toString());

    double altura = Double.parseDouble(alturaEd.getText().toString());

    double resultado = 655 + (9.6 * peso) + (1.8 * altura); //- (4.7 * nivel);


    finalEd.setText(String.format("%.02f", resultado));

}



public void addChangeListenerToRadios(){

    radioGrupo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            checklistValues[0] = (radio1.isChecked())?1.2:0;
            checklistValues[1] = (radio2.isChecked())?1.37:0;
            checklistValues[2] = (radio3.isChecked())?1.65:0;
            checklistValues[3] = (radio4.isChecked())?1.72:0;
            checklistValues[4] = (radio5.isChecked())?1.9:0;

            setNivelFromChecklist();

            updateValorTMB();

        }

    });

}

private void setNivelFromChecklist(){

    double total= 0;

    for (double item:checklistValues){

        total += item; 
    }

    nivel = total * .01;
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

UPDATE: NOW A NEW ERROR MESSAGE APPEARS!

Comment: It's on the image above!

Comment: your import is wrong, `import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;` delete that and import  right OnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: Thanks for the support but now a new message error appears!
I updated the image on the post

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966907/radiogroup-oncheckedchanged-function-wont-fire

Answer (score 1):

Type of `radioGrupo` should be changed to `RadioGroup` (`RadioButton radioGrupo;` -> `RadioGroup radioGrupo;` and `radioGrupo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);` -> `radioGrupo = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);`) and then you'll be able to use the following code:

```
radioGrupo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

    }
});
```